# How do i execute script in supervisor?

Tags: docker, hadoop, supervisord

I have a start-all.sh I specified it in CMD of docker. It works as expected.

**start-all.sh**

```
 #!/usr/bin/env bash

 echo "It's Me Dear"

 /etc/init.d/hadoop-hdfs-namenode start
 /etc/init.d/hadoop-hdfs-datanode start
 /etc/init.d/hadoop-hdfs-secondarynamenode start
 /etc/init.d/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce-tasktracker start

 sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -chmod 777 /
 /etc/init.d/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce-jobtracker start

 /etc/init.d/flume-ng-agent start

 /bin/bash
```

I can't able to specify the same file in supervisord. I tried

```
 [program:long_script]
 command=bash /usr/local/start-all.sh
```

start-all.sh present in the same file with mode 777. How do i resolve this?

```
 [program:job_tracker]
 command=bash -c "/etc/init.d/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce-jobtracker start"
```

It starts and exits. I checked the log file. It says permission denied. I have to add `sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -chmod 777 /` in the same command.

```
 command=bash -c "sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -chmod 777 /;/etc/init.d/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce-jobtracker start"
```

It doesn't work. I specified two commands but this also doen't work. Any idea?

**EDIT**

My file exists at /usr/local/start-all.sh How do i ensure whether supervisor is looking at correct directory?

Answer (score 1):

http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#program-x-section-settings

If you look at the example file (several screens down, they don't have an anchor for that spot), you'll see something like:

`directory=/tmp`

You can specify which directory to run the command from.

There is also a user option for supervisord.

`user=hdfs`

`If supervisord runs as root, this UNIX user account will be used as the account which runs the program. If supervisord can’t switch to the specified user, the program will not be started.`

Comment: I tried it. But it doesn't work. But `command=bash -c "/usr/local/start-all.h"` did what i wanted